# android autocomplete AsyncTask delay

Tags: android, android-asynctask, autocomplete

I'm implementing a location suggestion activity which populates  suggestions from an external server as the user types in a text view. I'm using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to fetch suggestions each time the text in the text view changes. When a new letter is typed, we cancel the task that already exists and execute a new one. Most of the time [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) starts immediately after [execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) is called, but other times it can take **a few seconds**. (Once doInBackground starts, performance is fine.)

Set listener:

```
private void init() {
    // respond to any text change
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int b, int c) {
            showSuggestions(s.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Here we start a new task and cancel the previous one:

```
private void showSuggestions(String query) {
    // suggestionsTask is an instance variable of the activity
    if (suggestionsTask != null) {
        suggestionsTask.cancel(true);
    }

    suggestionsTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Suggestion>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Suggestion> resultList) {
            // set suggestions with adapter - CHANGES STATE
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Suggestion> doInBackground(String... query) {
            // one local db call for recent searches - DOES NOT CHANGE STATE
            // one network call to external server - DOES NOT CHANGE STATE
            // return results
        }
    };

    suggestionsTask.execute(query);
}
```

Is there a better threading mechanism to use for this? Do you know why there is a delay between execute and doInBackground?

Comment: It could be that the tasks are serialized and a previous task its taking time to cancel.

Comment: That sounds very likely. Do you have an idea of how to get around that?

Answer (score 2):

From the [AsyncTask reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. **To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)**

So you're actually not canceling the doInBackground() step unless you're manually checking whether isCancelled() is set periodically in doInBackground. In most versions of Android, all AsyncTasks share a single thread, so one has to finish before the next can start. So that's the reason for your delay, but I don't have enough information (i.e., you didn't post the code) from your doInBackground() code to come up with a suggestion on where to check for isCancelled().

If being able to cancel the previous task not possible for some reason, you can also try making your AsyncTasks execute in parallel, using [executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)) with [THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) as the same documentation suggests, but with what you're trying to do that seems like it could cause some frustrating threading issues which would probably be worse than the one you're having right now.

Comment: "... THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR as the same documentation suggests, but with what you're trying to do that seems like it could cause some frustrating threading issues". How could there be threading issues if I cancel before each new execution and therefore only the latest task executes onPostExecute? My post doesn't include this but I tried to imply that the only global state that is modified is in onPostExecute: "set suggestions with adapter"

Comment: Well just the simplest example that comes to mind is, if you execute multiple AsyncTasks on different threads there's no guarantee that the first one you started will be the first one to finish. So you could end up going from a slow but correct solution to a faster but wrong one. Of course you can still use the thread pool executor, but it opens up problems that are hard to prepare for and, more annoyingly, don't fail consistently. It'd be much easier to just stick to the default executor and make sure you're actually cancelling the previous task with a loop in doInBackground(), in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with you in the general case, but given the code I included in the question, I think your assessment is too cautious/wrong here. "if you execute multiple AsyncTasks on different threads there's no guarantee that the first one you started will be the first one to finish" I don't care about the first one finishing first - only that the last one modifies the adapter last. I'm open to the possibility that my solution could be wrong if I use THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, but I'm not seeing the proof in your comments. Please address my earlier question: "How could there be... onPostExecute?"

Comment: Yes, by "there's no guarantee that the first one will finish first" I meant that there's no guarantee that the last one started will finish last.

Comment: Or maybe this is the confusion: You said "How could there be threading issues if I cancel before each new execution and therefore only the latest task executes onPostExecute?" but as I said in my answer, you're actually NOT cancelling the tasks when you just call AsyncTask.cancel(). The doInBackground() of the first task will actually finish doing everything, even after you have called cancel(), unless you manually check for it in a loop in doInBackground() and bail if you see that it's been cancelled.

Comment: I tried to make this clear in my code comments but I guess I did a bad job. The doInBackground doesn't actually change global state. The global state is only changed in onPostExecute. Although doInBackground might finish, the cancel will prevent it from running the onPostExecute since cancel causes onCancelled to be run instead. doInBackground's only job is to fetch results from db/networka nd return them. It does nothing else.

Comment: Ok, I can't stop you from doing it with the thread pool if you think that's always going to be the case, but your tasks are still running slow because you're not properly cancelling them, and it's better to fix the root of the problem than to add unnecessary complexity. For example, do you know how many threads are in that pool? I don't off the top of my head, but let's say it's 5. Then on your 6th task the operation is still going to have to wait for the 1st task to finish and you'll be having the same problem. I'm just saying it's easier to properly cancel than plan for crap like that.

Comment: I'm going to use threadpool and an isCancelled check before each of the two fetches. The isCancelled checks are not enough without the threadpool because I would have to pass the task through the db and network calls up until the last millisecond that the connection was made. Either would make my code incredibly disorganized with isCancelled checks all over or with just a couple the task can be cancelled in the middle of the network call and we'd have to wait for the network call to complete.

Comment: Sounds better than no check at all. Hope the advice helped you out. One more thought though: Why would you need to pass the task through your network/db calls? I don't know what networking library you're using but if you just kept a reference to the request object in the AsyncTask and then cancel the network call when the task is cancelled you might be able to do it without changing any non-task code?